# android memory usage and heap usage

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

when I look at my application in a memory utility (like Memory Usage app), it shows my application using 33MB of memory.

If while debugging my app, I go into DDMS and look at the heap, it's taking 4MB.

So at this point, I'm wondering where the other 29MB is being chewed up by.  Secondly, my concern is that I could wind up spending a huge amount of time trying to trim that 4MB to something much smaller like say 2-3MB, but that hardly seems like I'm putting a dent in the memory usage.  So how do i get that memory usage down much more significantly?

Answer (score 1):

check and discoer it properly..........

http://elinux.org/Android_Memory_Usage

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Comment: those articles are great, but still - where is that 29MB?  they only seem to talk about the 4MB...

Comment: according to the article, much of the memory is actually shared with other processes