# Analyze Android Memory Usage.

Tags: android, memory

Task Manager is showing a RAM usage of 10MB when my application is running. I wanted to analyze it, but when I create a hprof dump it only a shows a total of 2MB. Can anybody point me in the right direction to where the other 8MB come from?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613910/android-memory-usage-and-heap-usage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS for more accurate results. 
This difference might come from different queries. There is a difference between used and reserved (but free) memory. Maybe the TaskManager (which I wouldn't trust too much) shows the empty space and hprof also the reserved.